# Map multiple objects in an array in JOLT

Tags: json, mapping, transformation, jolt

There is a field called "item" which was needed only once because from the source I was only getting once. Now I am getting multiple times and my mapping is breaking. So, how should I handle this.

Field name is item.

Current Output-

[image]

Expected-

[image]

Below is the link with my old input, new input and current spec.

FYI-There are more field in the items tag. This is just for understanding

Link https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1vvdFBPwaHRVvjttUTQP0jzQlqYlGfjFZ

Comment: Dear @Sam. Please write the better question. Try to bring input and summarized output.

Comment: Hey @MohammadReza, input is very big I can't paste it here that why have uploaded it to GDrive. I have also framed the question in a better way now.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask - Write a title that summarizes the specific problem